# Error opening csv files on ftp server using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ftp

I have VBA code that opens csv files which are located on an ftp server using the following syntax:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="ftp://username:password@'ftpaddress'"
```

Each day of the month has its own file, and I must open every file in the current month. My issue is that after opening and manipulating several files, I get a `Run-time error 1004`: `Microsoft Excel cannot access the file.` 

If I hit Debug, and then continue, the macro will continue working. Any help would be appreciated.